# xml parser in ios

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

There  is the code

```
`-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@",elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"impproject"]) {
        impprojectdata=[[impProjectData  alloc]init];
        [impprojectdata setParentParserDelegate:self];
        [parser setDelegate:impprojectdata];
    }
}
```

`

then it come here:

```
    ` -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
        {
        NSLog(@"did start parser:%@", elementName);
        if ([elementName isEqual:@"project"]){

            ProjectDataItem *project=[[ProjectDataItem alloc]init];
            [project setParentParserDelegate:self];
            [parser setDelegate:project];
            [items addObject:project];
           }   
        }`


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"found character:%@", string);
    [currentString appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"did end parser:%@", elementName);
     currentString=nil;
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"improject"]) {
        [parser setDelegate:parentParserDelegate];
        NSLog(@"items.count is %d",items.count);

    }
}
```

then here

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"startElement %@",elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"DWMC_CN"]) {
        currentString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        self.name=currentString;
    }else if ([elementName isEqual:@"CZXMMC_CN"]){
        currentString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        self.title=currentString;
    }else if ([elementName isEqual:@"CNNAME"]){
        currentString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        self.name=currentString;
    }else if ([elementName isEqual:@"COMPANY"]){
        currentString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        self.title=currentString;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentString appendString:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    currentString =nil;
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"project"]) {
        [parser setDelegate:parentParserDelegate];
    }
}
```

then it come back the second part code;

So there is my question.  It's only add one object in the array 'items';

I don't get why...... 
Here is the github link:github.com/TedWei/gaojiaohui

Please help me . the ios new guy,poor guy.

I don't know  why the elementName is project.It will not creat the new object .and add it to array. It just exit....

Sorry for my english.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use readymade class available here : http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

its pretty well, it will return you a dictionary after pasring your xml data.

Comment: i have read this . but still want know what's wrong with my code.Thank's a lot,

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is now broken.